# Desabilitar option de um select ao clicar em um botão

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como faço para que quando eu clicar no botão eu desabilitar o `option` selecionado para que não possa ser escolhido novamente?

```html
<select name="produtos">
  <option value="1">Arroz</option>
  <option value="2">Feijão</option>
  <option value="3">Macarrão</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

Comment: Consegue explicar o porque precisa desabilitar o botão após o submit? Pode ser que você não precise realmente disso.

Comment: Isso após o submit?

Comment: Tah usando PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples assim amiguinho:

```js
function disable_select(){

  $("#produtos").prop('disabled',true);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="produtos" id='produtos'>
  <option value="1">Arroz</option>
  <option value="2">Feijão</option>
  <option value="3">Macarrão</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick='disable_select()'>
```

no `ONclick` do botão chama a função que desabilita o campo, com esse código jQuery:

```
 $("#produtos").prop('disabled',true);
```

**Se você quiser desabilitar somente o `option` selecionado:**

```js
function disable_select(){
  
  var id = $('#produtos').children(":selected").attr("id");
  $("#"+id).prop('disabled',true);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="produtos" id='produtos'>
      <option value="1" id='optArroz'>Arroz</option>
      <option value="2" id='optFeijao'>Feijão</option>
      <option value="3" id='optMacarrao' onclick='add_opt(optMacarrao)'>Macarrão</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick='disable_select()'>
```

Comment: Mas eu quero desabilitar apenas o option selecionado e não o select

Comment: hum, então pera ai

Comment: @LucasFonseca veja se é isso

Comment: Isso mesmo!! E um botão para habilitar novamente.. é possivel?

Comment: é possível sim, vou mostrar

Answer (score 0):

Altere o atributo type de submit para button e com evento onclick chame o validador JAVASCRIPT.
Usei Javascript puro pois não sei se você está usando alguma biblioteca.

```js
function validarForm(){
 var meuform = document.forms.meuformulario || document.forms['meuformulario'];
 meuform.produtos.disabled = true;
 meuform.submit();
}
```

```html
<form name="meuformulario" action="enviar.php">
<select name="produtos">
  <option value="1">Arroz</option>
  <option value="2">Feijão</option>
  <option value="3">Macarrão</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="validarForm()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma nova resposta com o botão de ativar, **já que ele me pediu nos comentários**.

```js
function disable_select(){
  
  var id = $('#produtos').children(":selected").attr("id");
  $("#"+id).prop('disabled',true);

}

function enable_select(){
  
  var id = $('#produtos').children(":selected").attr("id");
  $("#"+id).prop('disabled',false);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="produtos" id='produtos'>
      <option value="1" id='optArroz'>Arroz</option>
      <option value="2" id='optFeijao'>Feijão</option>
      <option value="3" id='optMacarrao'>Macarrão</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick='disable_select()'>
<button type="button" onclick='enable_select()'>Ativar</button>
```

Comment: você queria ativar todos de uma vez ou um só de cada vez?

Comment: Queria ativar apenas um de cada vez